# How to use <img> or <canvas> with "display: flex" layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**How can we have an `<img>` or `<canvas>` that stretches/shrinks to fill the remaining space in a `display: flex` type of layout?** It is straightforward to make a `<div>` fill the remaining space, but an `<img>` has its own idea of size that stops layout working properly. For example, suppose we have:

- a parent `<div>` with `display: flex`,
- a child `<h1>` with `flex: 0 0 auto`, and
- a child `<img>` with `flex: 1 1 0px`.

As the window is resized, the `<img>` (or `<canvas>`) sometimes fits exactly but sometimes overflows the parent depending on the size or aspect ratio of the window.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Simple Test</title>
        <style>
            body {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: column nowrap;
                margin: 0px;
                border: 4px dashed lightcoral;
            }
            h1 {
                flex: 0 0 auto;
                margin: 0px;
                border: 4px solid chocolate;
            }
            div {
                flex: 1 1 0px;
                border: 4px dotted darkorchid;
            }
            canvas {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border: 4px solid lightseagreen;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <div><canvas width="400" height="200"/></div>
    <script>
        var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas').item(0);
        var x = c.getContext('2d');
        x.ellipse(100, 100, 50, 50, 0, 0, 360);
        x.fill();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If this question should be deleted, that's fine, but I'm going to leave it because others might stumble onto it thinking the issue is specifically related to images or canvases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, this is related to the behavior of `flex-shrink`, which is explained well by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size).

In short, flex items have a default `min-width: auto` which usually means the content width (or height depending on the `flex-direction`). Simply set `min-width: 0` to allow the `<img>` or `<canvas>` to resize properly. This is perhaps more confusing in this case because it seems inappropriate to give these elements a minimum size.